# Fatal error: require(): Cannot redeclare class mailtohelper

Tags: fatal-error

I am getting the following error message on my Joomla site:

```
Fatal error: require(): Cannot redeclare class mailtohelper in /home/web/public_html/joomla/components/com_content/helpers/icon.php on line 84
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What version of Joomla? Have you made any changes to this file?

Comment: the version im using is joomla 3.4.8, and I immigrated to another server !

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on your new server?

Comment: i'm running PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: It might be that one of your extensions is causing the error. Please ensure you have updated all extensions

Comment: An extension is trying to redeclare a class mailtohelper. This error often occurs to me when I create new extension and forget to rename the class on the helper.php file. Try to disable latest extensions you recently installed and then enable one by one to find which one is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

A 3rd party extension is causing this. The mailtohelper shouldn't be invoked directly. Just use the Joomla mail object:

```
$mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
```

[Joomla Doc - Sending email from extensions](https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions)

Comment: Pretty sure he's hasn't even suggested he can code.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
require ('file_path_here');
```

try using

```
require_once('file_path_here');
```

Whenever you need any file to be included in the current page then remember,

**require()** includes file that previously been included.
**require_once()** ignore the file if it is previously been included in the same page.

try to figure out difference between include(), include_once(), require(), require_once() then use whichever is best for you.